# Counting longest sequence of specific elements in a list contained within a spark.sql database column

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following problem I would like to solve.

I have the following Dataframe that I created from a query

`val temp = spark.sql("select Id,  collect_list(from) as letter from f group by Id")`

```
|Id|                letter|
+-----------+---------------+
|      106|            [c]|
|      101|            [p]|
|      104|[c, c, c, t, u]|
|      100|[d, t, j, j, c]|
|      110|      [p, n, f]|
|      113|[s, c, c, b, ..|
|      115|[u, s, t, c, ..|
|       11|   [c, c, i, s]|
|      117|   [d, d, p, s]|
|      118|[a, s, c, t, ..|
|      123|         [d, n]|
|      125|         [n, b]|
|      128|            [c]|
|      131|   [c, t, c, u]|
|      132|      [c, u, i]|
|      134|[c, p, j, u, c]|
|      136|[b, a, t, n, c]|
|      137|         [b, a]|
|      138|      [b, t, c]|
|      141|            [s]|
```

I would like to create a new column called "n"
This column would contain a numerical value which represents the longest sequence of letters in a cell before "c" appears. the longest sequence can be anywhere in the list.

For example the solution column for this section (assuming nothing is cut off by the ....) would be

`0, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 1`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you add text instead of Image?

Comment: @koiralo done, does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use the spark `functions`, you can convert the given scala functions with spark `functions` as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("n_trip",
  array_max(
    transform(
      filter(
        split(array_join($"trip", " "), "co"),
        (col: Column) => (col =!= "" || col =!= null)
      ), (col: Column) => size(split(trim(col), " "))
    )
  ))
  .withColumn("n_trip", when($"n_trip".isNull, 0).otherwise($"n_trip"))
  .show(false)
```

Update: Easy to understand

```
  df.withColumn("split", split(array_join($"trip", " "), "co"))
    .withColumn("filter", filter($"split", (col: Column) => col =!= "" || col =!= null))
    .withColumn("n_trip", array_max(transform($"filter", (col: Column) => size(split(trim(col), " ")))))
    .withColumn("n_trip", when($"n_trip".isNull, 0).otherwise($"n_trip"))
    .drop("split", "filter")
    .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-----------+--------------------+------+
|passengerId|trip                |n_trip|
+-----------+--------------------+------+
|10096      |[co]                |0     |
|10351      |[pk]                |1     |
|10436      |[co, co, cn, tj, us]|3     |
|1090       |[dk, tj, jo, jo, ch]|5     |
|11078      |[pk, no, fr]        |3     |
|11332      |[sg, cn, co, bm]    |2     |
|11563      |[us, sg, th, cn]    |4     |
|1159       |[ca, cl, il, sg]    |4     |
|11722      |[dk, dk, pk, sg]    |4     |
|11888      |[au, se, ca, tj]    |4     |
|12394      |[dk, nl]            |2     |
|12529      |[no, be]            |2     |
|12847      |[cn]                |1     |
|13192      |[cn, tk, cg, uk]    |4     |
|13282      |[co, us, iq]        |2     |
|13442      |[cn, pk, jo, us, ch]|5     |
|13610      |[be, ar, tj, no, ch]|5     |
|13772      |[be, at]            |2     |
|13865      |[be, th, cn]        |3     |
|14157      |[sg]                |1     |
+-----------+--------------------+------+
```

Comment: I really like this solution, Could you please explain to me a little bit about how it works? thank you :)

Comment: @Xaleate this is mostly conversion of scala function solution. let me know if you didn't understand any of those function. You could do step by step with withColumn, for making it short I did it all in one.

Comment: Also check the updated part which might help you to understand step by step.

Comment: thanks Koiralo! that makes sense. I actually prefer that because it is clear to me. Just one thing though, when I run that I have the problem that n_trip is not resolved, is there a line missing where you make a duplicate before processing?

Comment: So there is a bit more wrong with the expanded solution you provided, the "neat" one works well but would love it if you could run the expanded one and see why its different then let me know how it should look, that would be very elpful!

Comment: check the updated, I might have missed some part before.

Comment: Hi sorry, yes I can do that :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a user defined function (udf) that would compute what you wish. There are plenty of ways to compute the longuest sequence. One simple way is to split the sequence on `"co"`, compute the size of each sub sequence and take the max.

```scala
val longuest_seq = udf((x : Seq[String]) => {
    x.reduce(_ +" "+_)
     .split(" *co *")
     .map(_.count(_ == ' ') + 1)
     .max
})

val df = Seq(
    (1, Array("x", "y", "co", "z")),
    (2, Array("x")),
    (3, Array("co", "t")),
    (4, Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "co", "e"))
).toDF("id", "trip")

df.withColumn("n_trips", longuest_seq('trip)).show
```

which yields

```
+---+-------------------+-------+
| id|               trip|n_trips|
+---+-------------------+-------+
|  1|      [x, y, co, z]|      2|
|  2|                [x]|      1|
|  3|            [co, t]|      1|
|  4|[a, b, c, d, co, e]|      4|
+---+-------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply oli, this doesn't actually compute what I would like though, and how do I use the UDF on the data frame?

Comment: Sorry, I copied paste the wrong code. It's fixed.

Comment: ah yes I see how that works, thanks for the advice!